# Mongoose find and update all

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

So currently I am using this

```
await User.findOneAndUpdate({email: req.user.email }, {lastLoad: 'dfConsignee'});
```

But I want to be able to update all users with the same truckNumber to be updated when the form is submitted.

SO I tried using this

```
await User.update({truckNumber: truckNumber }, {lastLoad: 'dfConsignee'});
```

But this only updated the active user for some reason. How would I go about updating all the accounts with the same truck number on form completion?

Thank you guys in advance <3

Edit ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

By active user, I meant logged in user.

Mongoose Schema:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    date: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    },
    isVerified: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false
    },
    profilePic: {
        type: String,
        default: 'abc'
    },
    truckDriver: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false
    },
    truckNumber: {
        type: Number
    },
    admin: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false
    },
    customer: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false
    },
    loadPlanning: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false
    },
    lastLoad: {
        type: String,
        default: "dfConsignee"
    }
});

const User = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);

module.exports = User;
```

Sample Document:

```
{"_id":{"$oid":"aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"},
"isVerified":true,
"profilePic":"abc",
"truckDriver":true,
"admin":false,
"customer":false,
"loadPlanning":false,
"lastLoad":"aAtShipper",
"name":"Nicholas Cage",
"email":"NicholasCage@thegreatestactorever.com",
"password":"password",
"date":{"$date":{"$numberLong":"1580858993547"}},"__v":{"$numberInt":"0"},
"truckNumber":"123",}
```

To add a bit more clarification, when the form is submitted, it will pull the logged in users truck number. When the form is submitted, I am wanting everyone who shares that same truck number to have their value in lastLoad be updated as well.

Comment: what do you mean by active user ? what's the difference between active user vs inactive user in your document ? Also can you give your sample docs for one being updated & one not being updated..

Comment: Can you add mongoose schema code and sample document?

Comment: I agree with the above requests for more info - if my answer didn't work it sounds like something else is off in your code rather than there being something wrong with Mongoose or your DB.

Comment: Added additional information and added clarification

Answer (score 1):

Try using `updateMany()`. The resulting code would look something like this:

```
User.updateMany({truckNumber: truckNumber}, {lastLoad: 'dfConsignee'});
```

If you really want to familiarize yourself with Mongoose and MongoDB as a whole, I'd suggest taking a look at the [API docs for Mongoose](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html) and the [MongoDB Manual](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/), it goes into much more detail about the tools you have available to you when using MongoDB. That's how I found the answer to this question!

Comment: I just tried this one as well (thought I'd post while searching API docs in case I don't find it)

```
await User.updateMany({truckNumber: truckNumber }, {lastLoad: 'aAtShipper'});
```

But it was still only updating the account I was submitting the form through, it wasn't updating the other accounts that had the same truck number :(

Hoping that adding this 
```
await User.updateMany({truckNumber: truckNumber }, {"$set": {lastLoad: 'aAtConsignee'}});
```
Will hopefully fix it

Comment: What version of Mongoose/MongoDB are you using?

Comment: Mongoose version 5.8.3

Comment: Also, just tried this:              

await User.update({truckNumber: truckNumber }, {lastLoad: 'dfConsignee'}, {"multi": true});                         

Same result

Answer (score 1):

OMG Finally figured this out :D

I thought that when I restarted Nginx it would restart the app running on the server ( I would see front end changes doing this, but the back end changes wouldn't show up), once I restarted PM2 all the back end changes came along with it.

Thank you everyone for the help :D

Now "await Users.updateMany({truckNumber: req.user.truckNumber}, {lastLoad: 'aAtShipper'}" will update all accounts with a shared truck Number :D